# Why third partition of /dev/sda is shown as /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sda3?

Tags: fdisk, df, partition-table

I have two 3 TB disks in hardware RAID-1 (mirroring), controller DELL PERC H310 (it is a Dell PowerEdge R420 server).

I have three partitions on the same disk.

`df` and `fdisk` commands shows the third partition as `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda3`.

I cannot understand why works in this way.

```
[root@ru000397 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        91G  5.6G   81G   7% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        2.6T   17G  2.5T   1% /usr/local/psa

[root@ru000397 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0b14c924

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       12035    96664576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           12035       13055     8190976   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2892.7 GB, 2892660473856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 351679 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Comment: What makes you think it's a partition?  Nothing here shows that.  More likely is it's a separate volume on the raid controller.  Even though the disks in use may be the same, virtually it is a different device.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know RAID controllers offers this kind of abstraction. How I can check the configuration of the RAID controller?

Comment: Reboot and hit CTRL+whatever it is for that controller (I think it's CTRL+R on the PERCs), install Dell OMSA (open manage) or install the cli that can query the controller.  I don't recall which one that is for the H310.  I use OMSA on Dell systems myself.  The [Dell System Update](http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/) instructions can get you setup on that pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you. I will install such programs. Just saw the volumes from my iDRAC web interface :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your 3 TB drives are split into two separate LUNs or Virtual Disks, a smaller one for boot, and the rest for your plesk data.  It appears the OS you chose doesn't support 2TB+ as a boot volume (which isn't necessarily a bad thing)

Follow the comments to confirm this in your PERC raid utility at boot (CTRL+R). If you didn't confirm your raid configuration from factory, this is exactly what I would expect.

If you want to boot 2TB+ you'll need UEFI and a supported OS with GPT.